# Powershell : how to merge 2 csv files

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'd like to merge 2 csv in 1, I tried many ways but unfortunately I don't have enougth skill

I thank you for your help

an example

**file1.csv**

```
Flags;KeyID;UserID
[Vt---];0x999999;SERVER1
[Vt---];0x888888;SERVER2
[Vt-E-];0x666666;SERVER3
[Vt---];0x444444;SERVER4
```

**file2.csv**

```
;KeyCreationDate;KeyExpirationDate;Status(1);Status(2)
;2017-02-20;2022-02-20;True;False
;2019-07-18;2024-07-17;True;False
;2016-11-24;2021-11-24;False;False
;2021-09-22;2023-09-22;True;False
```

and the result should be

**file3.csv**

```
Flags;KeyID;UserID;KeyCreationDate;KeyExpirationDate;Status(1);Status(2)
[Vt---];0x999999;SERVER1;2017-02-20;2022-02-20;True;False
[Vt---];0x888888;SERVER2;2019-07-18;2024-07-17;True;False
[Vt-E-];0x666666;SERVER3;2016-11-24;2021-11-24;False;False
[Vt---];0x444444;SERVER4;2021-09-22;2023-09-22;True-False
```

I tried something like this and I try to combine a double loop :

```
$file1 = Get-Content C:\file1.csv
$file2 = Get-Content C:\file2.csv

for ($i = 1; $i -lt $file1.Length; $i++)
{  
([string]$file1[$i]).Split(';')[0] | out-host;
([string]$file1[$i]).Split(';')[1] | out-host;
([string]$file1[$i]).Split(';')[2] | out-host;
([string]$file1[$i]).Split(';')[3] | out-host;
([string]$file1[$i]).Split(';')[4] | out-host;
([string]$file1[$i]).Split(';')[5] | out-host;
([string]$file1[$i]).Split(';')[6] | out-host;
([string]$file1[$i]).Split(';')[7] | out-host;
([string]$file1[$i]).Split(';')[8] | out-host;
([string]$file1[$i]).Split(';')[9] | out-host;
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this... and blocked :S

Answer (score 0):

finaly I coded this :

```
$file1 = Get-Content C:\Scripts\PGP\PubKeys\PubKeysExpired.csv
$file2 = Get-Content C:\Scripts\PGP\PubKeys\dates.csv

for ($j = 0; $j -lt $file1.Length; $j++)
{   
    ([string]$file1[$j]) + ([string]$file2[$j]) 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).